# How to achieve a strike through like effect

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm looking for an effect similar to `---- or ----`. However, the code below is creating a strike through effect. I thought that setting `Grid.ZIndex` would solve the issue, however it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="or" FontSize="22" Height="34" Grid.ZIndex="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Line Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" X1="1" Margin="0 4 0 -1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.ZIndex="1" Height="34" />
</Grid>
```

If I set a background to my `TextBlock` control then all works fine. What I want, though, is to use the default gray background (e.g. not set a background at all).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish if it isn't a strikethrough.  What do the dashes mean?

Comment: The dashes are supposed to be a straight line. I'm not sure how to better convey it. It's essentially a strike through of the control as a whole but not the text itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was actually quite simple.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="or" FontSize="22" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
    <Line Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" X1="1" Margin="0 4 0 -1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="34" Grid.ZIndex="-99" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 13):

It's better to use `TextDecorations`

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.TextDecorations>
        <TextDecoration Location="Strikethrough">
            <TextDecoration.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="Red" />
            </TextDecoration.Pen>
        </TextDecoration>
    </TextBlock.TextDecorations>
    Strike through
</TextBlock>
```